# error: type mismatch; found: Unit.type required: Unit

Tags: scala

Code snippets are from the Scala REPL.

This is perfectly legal Scala even though it is not very useful:

```
scala> class Test {
  private val xs = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]()
  private val func = Some((x: Int)=>{
  })
  private var opt: Option[(Int)=>Unit] = None
  opt = func
}
defined class Test
```

However, if I try to do something inside `func` the code will not compile:

```
scala> class Test {
  private val xs = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]()
  private val func = Some((x: Int)=>{
    xs += x
  })
  private var opt: Option[(Int)=>Unit] = None
  opt = func
}
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Some[Int => Test.this.xs.type]
 required: Option[Int => Unit]
         opt = func
               ^
```

Instead it produces the type mismatch error and lists the types found and required. While this error message is useful, I don't know how to fix it. My next attempt was this:

```
scala> class Test {
  private val xs = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]()
  private val func = Some((x: Int)=>{
    xs += x
    Unit
  })
  private var opt: Option[(Int)=>Unit] = None
  opt = func
}
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Some[Int => Unit.type]
 required: Option[Int => Unit]
         opt = func
               ^
```

I understand that there is a type mismatch occurring, but I don't understand why there is a type mismatch or how to fix it in such a way that I can do something useful inside `func`.

Why is there a type mismatch and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function inside options uses mutable array buffer and returns it as a result, but you need Unit, you can do it this way:

```
private val func = Some((x: Int)=> {xs += x; ()})
```

or use append which return type is Unit

```
private val func = Some((x: Int) => xs.append(x))
```

Comment: So it looks like I was on the right track when I tried to specify Unit as the last line of the function. What is the difference between `Unit` and `()`?

Comment: It's the same basically, new Unit == () == "java void"

Comment: Basically, but not really. `()` compiles while `Unit` does not. I guess I can ask a different question for that.

Comment: Just "Unit" - it's the name of the type, and '()' instance of type Unit, so that's why you had problems with last try

Comment: but Unit is a special type, so it's not "real instance of Unit type", for type system it feels like an instance

Comment: Well actually what happens is that the `Unit` **type** has a companion **object** (whose name is thus also `Unit`, and whose type is `Unit.type`). In axiopisty's code it is that latter that was returned (when (s)he should have returned `()`). It's no different than trying to return `Int` in a function with return type `Int` (this will return the `Int` companion, typed as `Int.type`) instead of returning say `123` .